# Programmatically select the subviews of UIView in iOS

Tags: ipad, uiview, ios4, uigesturerecognizer, subviews

How do i programmatically select the subviews of a UIView.

Senario:
Consider a UIView has 10 UIImageViews added as subview on it. 
How can i select 5 of them through gesture?
What could be the gesture performed by user on iPad to select those 5 UIImageViews?
How can i programmatically capture the selection?

Please help,

Thank You,
Suse.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution. You can declare an NSMutableArray, say called lastChosenViews.

```
  NSMutableArray *lastChosenViews;
```

(Off course you need to allocate and initialize it somewhere, maybe in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear methods).

Then you can use touchesEnded method to add the touched view to the lastChosenViews array.

```
 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
     UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
     if ([lastChosenViews count]==5)
        [lastChosenViews removeObjectAtIndex:0];
     [lastChosenViews addObject:touch.view];
 }
```

Then you can use the lastChosenViews array wherever you want.

P.S.You can also check for the touch.tapCount if you want. For special gestures use UIGestureRecognizer subclasses UIPinchGestureRecognizer,UIRotationGestureRecognizer,UISwipeGestureRecognizer,UIPanGestureRecognizer
UILongPressGestureRecognizer